# How to delete the specific image in folder using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code-igniter. In my project i would like to delete the specific image in folder(artical_images). If i try to use delete_files() option it deletes all the images in the folder when use the code like,

```
public function delete_post($value='$id')
    {

        $query=$this->db->query("select artical_profile from articals where artical_id='$value' ");

        $img_name=$query->result()[0]->artical_profile;

        //echo $img_name;

        delete_files('./artical_images/',TRUE);

       // $this->db->where('artical_id',$value);
        //$this->db->delete('articals');

        exit();

    }
```

But when i include the specific image name taken from db and include with delete file path it doesn't work.The code is below,

```
public function delete_post($value='$id')
    {

        $query=$this->db->query("select artical_profile from articals where artical_id='$value' ");

        $img_name=$query->result()[0]->artical_profile;

        //echo $img_name;

        delete_files('./artical_images/$img_name',TRUE);

       // $this->db->where('artical_id',$value);
        //$this->db->delete('articals');

        exit();

    }
```

even i included the realpath option it also not works,

```
public function delete_post($value='$id')
    {

        $query=$this->db->query("select artical_profile from articals where artical_id='$value' ");

        $img_name=$query->result()[0]->artical_profile;

        $img_name=realpath(APPPATH . '/artical_images/$img_name');

        delete_files('$img_name',TRUE);

        echo $img_name;

       // $this->db->where('artical_id',$value);
        //$this->db->delete('articals');

        exit();

    }
```

please give some idea to delete the files,

Comment: Check if $img_name contains the proper image name or not and if you have the permission to delete the file or not?

Comment: ya.image name is same as what is in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
```

Comment: yes, i auto load the helper "file".But it not works.

Comment: otherwise use unlink(FILE_PATH) this function

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/blog_creation/artical_images/artical_images/nboopathilb@gmail_com.jpg): No such file or directory

i include the path and what the image name in folder but it shows as no such file or directory.why????

Comment: $filepath=FCPATH ."upload path/image name";
unlink($filepath);
try like this one

Comment: thank you very much rajen antarkar i got it...from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`delete_files` uses a directory path to delete all the files in the directory. It applies the recursive `unlink` command to delete files.

To delete particular file, You can use `unlink` with the proper file path.

e.g. `unlink(FILE_PATH);`

Comment: is i want to take the application path or not??or i want to simply add the folder name and image name onl,in the place of file path.

Comment: Use full path of the file using APPPATH.

Comment: unlink('C:/xampp/htdocs/blog_creation/artical_images/artical_images/'.$img_name); i included the full path where the img stored . its not working

Comment: is `$image_name` contains file extension?

Comment: And also check folder permission. Is it allowing to delete the file or not?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful then you should up vote it.

Comment: @BoopathiN You can accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: i also like to vote to you,but i not crossed the 15 reputations,so stack overflow not allow me to vote any one.